# Multiple criteria for dummy in scoreboard (Minecraft)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know how to give points using scoreboard when a player gets wood, `/scoreboard objectives add Wood stat.mineBlock.17 PointsWood`, and I know how to give points with scoreboard when stone is mined, `/scoreboard objectives add Stone stat.mineBlock.1 PointsStone`. But what if I want the points in the same variable to increase if you mine wood AND if you mine stone? Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the testing command block that tests for if the player has 1 of the stone/wood stat (`/testfor @a[score_wood_min=1,score_wood=1]`), put a comparator facing outwards from the block and put two more command blocks after the comparator, one that removes the score from the wood/stone stat, and another one that adds 1 to the final variable (`/scoreboard players add @a[score_wood_min=1,score_wood=1] PointsWoodStone 1`).